# How can i reveal hidden qr code on grayscale image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

Hi i have a image hided qr code inside.
I tried some methods on internet but neither of them did not work.
How can i reveal the hidden qr code by using OpenCV or ImageMagick?

Image is here: [qr.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyzQE.png)

I want to achieve that the result image is readable from common qr code readers.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is visible if you bring up the contrast. For example in Imagemagick:

```
convert qrcode_hidden.png -brightness-contrast 0,90 x.png
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, is there a way to achieve it as black and white?

Comment: It will not look good because of all the background noise.

Comment: It looks like one started with a normal QR code image. Then an edge detection was applied to show only the bright and dark edges of the outline. Then this was superimposed onto a noise gray background.  I do not know any way to easily and directly reverse this process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dynamic line profile which shows the intensities of the pixels as I move the mouse pointer left-to-right across the image. On the right side, you will see the positive and negative peaks as the pointer transitions from  bright to dark areas and from dark to bright - the peaks go the other way.

[image]

If you were really keen to recover the QR code, you could scan the image one line at a time and plot with black and white changing colour each time you encounter a peak flipped the other way.

---

If you normalise the image first, the peaks and troughs are easier to detect:

```
magick qr.png -normalize qr-norm.png
```

[image]

---

Note that you can calculate the horizontal and vertical *"projections"* of the image by summing the pixels across the rows and down the columns and normalising the results. These are shown across the bottom and down the right side of the original image in the diagram below.

This should give you some insight as to where the fiducial markers are and also where the boundaries of the QR-code modules lie and how big each module is.

[image]

---

As Fred says, there is lots of noise too, so you may have to do some clean-up afterwards if you know the size of the modules or want to deduce the size of the modules from the fiducial markers at the corners.

Comment: Thanks, you both contributed useful answers :)

Comment: One concept to recover would be to scan horizontally from left to right. Mark black until you get to a bright white line. Mark white until you get to an equally dark line. Continue with black until reaching a bright white line, etc.  Then repeat forming a new image when scanning vertically downward.  Then combine the two resulting black and white images. This would have to be coded. I don't think there are readily available tools to do that.